# How to properly extract desired information using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Recently, I decided to play a little bit with **Jsoup** and its various properties. In order to do that I created small application which gathers informations from the following website (http://sunwell.pl).

Now (if you look at the website) I would like to get info about players on-line.

### HTML Code

```
<span class="zalogowany-jako-username" style="font-size: 20px;">Players online: 791</span>
```

### My Code

```
public void read(String webAddress) throws IOException {

        document = Jsoup
                .connect(webAddress)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
                .get();
        elements = document.select("span[class=zalogowany-jako-username]");
        System.out.println(elements);
    }
```

### Results

After I execute my program, it prints nothing at all (luckily there is also no error). My question is why? Could anyone correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Jsoup` does **NOT** support `JavaScript`. The piece of `html` code you are trying to get is generated by `JavaScript`, hence it is visible on a browser, but not available for `Jsoup` because `Jsoup` cannot render `JavaScript` and will only retrieve pure `HTML` code.

A good way to see if `Jsoup` can retrieve a content is to get the entire web page with `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get()`, then do `System.out.println(doc.html())` to see the retrieved content. I've done this with your url and found out the `tag` you want does not exist.

---

**UPDATE:**

One thing you can do is to use the **developer tool** of the Chrome browser, open the network tab, select `XHR` as your filter, then refresh the page to see where the website gets the `AJAX` information from.

I've done this with your website and found out that the website retrieves information from the following url: "**http://sunwell.pl/getstatuscode.php**". So instead of your original url, please try with this one. This will get you the information you need!

[image]
[image]

Comment: okay, seems logic. Is there any API which actually supports JS?

Comment: It does work. Thank you very much for fast answer :)